# Common Lisp function that unwraps a list to reveal the sequence of elements inside the list?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I want to apply the `union` function to the lists within a list. For example:

apply `union` to the lists inside this list: `'((a b c) (a d))`

Is there a function that "unwraps" a list, to reveal the sequence of elements inside the list? For example:

unwrapping this list `'((a b c) (a d))` produces this sequence `'(a b c) '(a d)`

If I could do that, then I could apply the `union` function to the sequence.

What is the recommended idiom for taking the `union` of a sequence of lists contained within a list?

Comment: I propose reading a basic Lisp book which explains list operations, applying functions, mapping and reducing.

Comment: To call a function with zero or more arguments with the last argument(s) as a list of arguments you use [`apply`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_apply.htm).

Comment: For example read chapter 7: https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~dst/LispBook/book.pdf

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
CL-USER 15 > (reduce #'union '((a b c) (a d)))
(D A B C)
```